# get current page/url in attribute selector

Tags: html, css

I am trying to style some text menu in my css, when the link of that menu equals the current url. But doesn't seem to work. This is the sentence:

```
#pages.tabs ul li a[href$=location]{color:blue !important;}
```

, where `#pages.tabs ul li` is the menu list where are located those links. I guessed the `location` thing contained the current url in css. But i don't even know if this can be achieved only with css.

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: You can't do that with only CSS. You need server side script or JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only use `addClass` or `removeClass` from JQuery.

Css code:

```
.liactive{background-color:#3C6EC9;}
```

---

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('ul li').click(function(){
  var items=$('ul li').get();
  for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++)
  $(items[i]).removeClass('liactive');
  $(this).addClass('liactive');
 });

});
```

---

I made this code for you. Have fun ^^
Here is your example --------> [Knee's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CaptKnee/cSNjM/)

Comment: thank you very much, sorry for late reply. I don't know if I can insert this code in my web, because it is a blogger site with 'dynamic view' template enabled. Because of this, I was trying to do it only via css.

Comment: Slightly simpler, more readable JQ solution (1) 2 lines of code in the event handler (removeClass & addClass), (2) cut out extra html (<ul><li> are superfluous bloat here) - http://jsfiddle.net/bhilleli/e0cu3kb2/14/

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with `css` only you need to use `javascript` too. Give a class to current url li and give styling from css. like

Html

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul>
       <a href="../index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
       <a href="usefulsites.html"><li>Useful Sites</li></a>
       <a href="software.html"><li class="currentpage">Software</li></a>
       <a href="workbench.html"><li>The Workbench</li></a>
       <a href="contact.php"><li>Contact</a></li></a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
.currentpage {
   color: #640200;
   background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Can I embeed a javascript function inside css template (using <script type="text/javascript">) that get url to a variable and then use it in the selector?

Comment: you can use script tag.